# How do I read data from Amazon DynamoDB?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I want the response in JSON format. Is there something out of box from DynamoDB or do I have to implement a RESTful service?

Comment: https://zappysys.com/blog/how-to-query-amazon-dynamodb-read-write-update/

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Unfortunately, your question isn't very detailed and it is hard to give you an answer. Please Edit your question and add information such as what you are wanting to accomplish, what you've tried so far (source code encouraged!) and what problem you are experienced. That way, there will be a better chance of receiving a useful answer. Also let us know your programming language.

Answer (score 0):

You can develop an AWS Lambda function and read data from DynamoDB.

then use API Gateway to create an API to expose Lambda function.

Answer (score 0):

I did with both Lambda and javascript file in S3.

JS file in S3:

```
var dynamodb = new AWS.DynamoDB({
    apiVersion: '2012-08-10'
});

var params = {
    TableName: "movies"
};

dynamodb.scan(params, function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err, err.stack);
    } else {
        console.log(data);
    }
)};
```

In Lambda:

```
var doc = require('dynamodb-doc'),
    db = new doc.DynamoDB(),
    aws = require('aws-sdk'),
    s3 = new aws.S3({apiVersion: '2006-03-01'});

var params = {
    TableName: "movies"
};

dynamodb.scan(params, function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err, err.stack);
    } else {
        console.log(data);
    }
)};
```